# Bingmap api provide same cordinates if zipcode is same and address is different

Tags: c#, rest, bing-maps

I am facing following issue. I have 2 address with same zipcode. I use BingMap API. The point is both provides same cordinates.

**Address 1:**

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine=chandranagar, Near PPCC ground&postalCode=380007&maxResults=1?key=yourBingMapsKey
```

**Address 2:**

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine=C603 satva flats near shantivan chandranagar&postalCode=380007&maxResults=1?key=yourBingMapsKey
```

Both of above address provide same result.

**Code:**

```
string bingMapsUri = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?" + mapAddress + "&key=" + bingMapKey;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{                                         
    string response = client.DownloadString(bingMapsUri);
    response = response.Replace("__type", "mytype");
    LocationQueryResponse root = new LocationQueryResponse();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(root.GetType());
    root = ser.ReadObject(ms) as LocationQueryResponse;
    ms.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you escape your strings properly in your real request?

Comment: Your Urls seem wrong. Check them again, you got two ?, whitespaces and other stuff in your URL

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your addressLine values are not address lines but point of interest queries that are not supported in geocoders. What you are looking for is a free form point of interest/business listing API. I'm not aware of any such API that has good coverage in India. If you decide to use the Bing Maps geocoding service for addresses, be sure to use the best practices: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx If using .NET, take a look at the Bing Maps REST .NET toolkit which already implements all the best practices for you and is easy to use: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit